# Ionic with crosswalk crash on open android 7

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk, android-7.0-nougat, oneplusthree

I installed my ionic app with crosswalk on android 7, crashes everytime I open it. Works on every other android version. Uninstall crosswalk, still crashes on open. Any idea?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall Crosswalk you have to delete the files on `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`, then build again.

About the crash is a very know bug https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7214. We have to wait or try to help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem, but it was linked to  `'com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions'`
in my case.

If you have `<preference name="CrosswalkAnimatable" value="true"/>` in config.xml, set it to false, and remove nativepagetransitions plugin if installed.

Answer (score 1):

Set android target sdk to 23

```
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

In my application croswalk version is 2.2.0 but it may also work with latest version 2.3.0 did not test with latest version.

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" version="2.2.0" />
```

Now it will work with android 7 also. This is the only workaround I had. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it done by moving

```
<preference name="CrosswalkAnimatable" value="true" />
```

inside

```
<platform name="ios">
```

tag.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
```